# Contact form to send email to a specific person

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a simple contact form for my church website. It will email to the address(es) I put in the code. But here is what I want to add. I'd like the visitor to be able to enter reason for contact (Information or Prayer Request) and the message. But also, if they want to contact a specific staff member (selected from drop down), they can and it does not sent to the info/prayer email, but to that staff member's address. Right now, I have the staff dropdown list, but the email only goes to the designated address for the form in general, not to the staff member's address when chosen. Does that make sense?

In other words, someone will receive emails requesting info. or prayer and the staff members will receive email sent directly to them. Is that possible? Thank you in advance for any input.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form id="contactusForm" method="post" action="connect.php">
    <div><blockquote>Please fill out this short form and we will respond as soon as possible. Nothing is required except your reason for contact and your message.</blockquote>

    </div> 


    <label for="reason">Reason</label>
    </div><div class="col-75">
 <select name="reason" id="reason" type="select" tabindex="1">
      <option value="select">Select One</option>
     <option value="prayer@mlc.org">Request For Prayer</option>
     <option value="info@mlc.org">Request For Information</option>
     <option value="john@mlc.org">Contact Pastor John</option>
          <option value="dennis@mlc.org">Contact Assistant Pastor Dennis </option>
          <option value="bryan@mlc.org">Contact Assistant Pastor Bryan</option>
          <option value="kellie@mlc.org">Contact Kid's Pastor Kellie</option>
          </select></div> </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name.." tabindex="3" title="Name" size="50" maxlength="50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number.." tabindex="4" title="Phone" size="30" maxlength="30">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email..." tabindex="5" title="Email" size="50" maxlength="50" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="state">State</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <select name="state" id="state" type="select" tabindex="6">
                <option value="">Select your state...</option>
                <option value="NA">N/A</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <select name="country" id="country" type="select" tabindex="7">
                <option value="">Select your country...</option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option> 
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>   
    <p>If you would like to email a specific staff member, please select one below.</p>
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25" id="selectStaff">
            <label for="emailTo">Staff Member</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <select name="emailTo" id="emailTo" type="select" tabindex="1">
                <option value="select">Select One</option>
                <option value="john@mlc.org">Pastor John</option>
                <option value="dennis@mlc.org">Assistant Pastor Dennis</option>
                <option value="bryan@mlc.org">Assistant Pastor Bryan</option>
                <option value="dennis@missionlighthouse.org">Kid's Pastor Kellie</option>
            </select>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <textarea name="message" type="text" maxlength="800" required="required" id="message" style="height:180px" placeholder="Type your message here..." tabindex="8"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contact_me_by_email_only" value="1" style="display:none !important" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" tabindex="10" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'PHP/PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$emailto = $_POST['emailTo'];
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//validation
if(empty($message)){
    header("location: connect.html?nomessage");
}

$honeypot = FALSE;
if (!empty($_REQUEST['contact_us_by_email_only']) && (bool) $_REQUEST['contact_us_by_email_only'] == TRUE) {
    $honeypot = TRUE;
    log_spambot($_REQUEST);
    # treat as spambot
} else {
    # process as normal

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.domain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'test@mlc.org';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'Password';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('test@mlc.org', 'MLC Website');
        $mail->addAddress('noone@nowhere.net', 'John G.');
          $mail->addAddress('someone@gmail.com', 'Someone');
        // Add a recipient

        //Body Content
        $body = "<p><strong>Hello</strong>, you have received a message submitted from the MLC Website.<br><br>

        <br><strong>Message Topic:</strong><br>" . $reason.
        "<br><br><strong>Name:</strong><br>" . $name.
        "<br><br><strong>Phone:</strong><br>" . $phone.
        "<br><br><strong>Email:</strong><br>" . $email. 
        "<br><br><strong>State:</strong><br>" . $state. 
      "<br><br><strong>Country:</strong><br>" . $country.
        "<br><br><strong>Message:</strong><br>". $message."</p>";

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Email from MLC Website';
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags ($body);
        $mail->send();

        header("Location: thankyou.html?sent");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking about `if ($reason=="Prayer") { $toAddr = "else@..."; }` ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. If Prayer than (prayer@....) Or if Information then (info@...)  Or if Staff Member then (one_selected@....) I could do it like that? But of course in PHP language. Ha.

Comment: I modified my HTML some. I think this is what I want.

Comment: Then just modify the PHP portion to utilize the field value for `→…Address()` instead of a static mail address. Notably you should ensure the value is only of the allowed targets - to prevent this form becoming an open relay.

Comment: I'm sorry Mario, I don't know what you mean. I am a beginner at PHP.